# Channel capability V2_0 is required but not supported Fabric V2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm getting this error with orderer while launching a Fabric v2 network

```
Channel capability V2_0 is required but not supported
```

My `configtx.yaml`'s Capabilities section

```
Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V2_0: true
```

Generated channel artifacts with `configtxgen` v2.0.0

```
 $ configtxgen --version
configtxgen:
 Version: 2.0.0
 Commit SHA: 0432c3e80
 Go version: go1.13.4
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
```

Using `hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest` docker image.

Any suggestion what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest tag points to the 1.4 image, not the 2.0 image. I can't remember exactly what the discussion around the `latest` tag was but I don't believe its planned to be updated, ie it's intentional that latest hasn't been changed to point to 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Met the same problem, specified orderer and tools image tag to 2.2 and it works.